# Plot a 3-D surface from a table of coordinates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I haven't found an answer to this yet: I have a grid defined in a text file with four columns: (lon,lat,depth,slip). Each row is a grid point.

I can generate a scatter plot of these points using the following simple code:

```
# Main imports:
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Read the grid:
points = np.loadtxt("grid.txt")

# Retrieve parameters from the grid:
lon = points[:,0]
lat = points[:,1]
depth = points[:,2]
slip = points[:,3]

# 3-D plot of the model:
fig = figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
p = ax.scatter(lon, lat, depth, c=slip, vmin=0, vmax=max(slip), s=30, edgecolor='none', marker='o')
fig.colorbar(p)
title("Published finite fault in 3-D")
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude [degrees]")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude [degrees]")
ax.set_zlabel("Depth [km]")
ax.invert_zaxis()
jet()
grid()
show()
```

And I get the following figure:
[image: Grid in 3-D. The color of each point represents the "slip" values.]
What I want to do is to be able to interpolate those points to create a "continuous" surface grid and plot it in both 2-D and 3-D plots. Therefore, somehow I've to consider all (lon,lat,depth,slip) in the interpolation. I'd appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [tri-surface-plots](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots)

Comment: It could work, but how can I account for the values in the fourth column (slip)? I'm trying to do that right now, still unsuccessfully.

Comment: I’m sure there are many examples of trisurf out there... you  just have to search for them

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597026/python-3d-plots-over-non-rectangular-domain). It depends a bit on how your data is ordered (which is unknown here).

Comment: In my data file, none of the columns are sorted in any way. I've checked some examples of trisurf. For a 2-D plot, the 'slip' values of my data could be used in 'z'. But in a 3-D plot, the grid is a plane with an azimuth and dip, and each point has a value of 'slip' that I want to interpolate and color on the plane. That is the main difficulty.

Comment: If you think the linked question and answers do not help here, could you, based on those, reformulate your question with actual data that reproduce the problem? (In the limit, take over the data from the "unstructured plot_trisurf" example, or modify it as to fit your case)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but if your data grid is properly ordered, you could resolve your iusse using plot_surface reshaping your 1D data to 2D.
An example supposing you're using a 10x10 grid:

```
# Main imports:
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# Set the fourth dimension` 
color_dimension = slip.reshape(10,10)  

# normalize the colours
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx) 
# color map
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='hot')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
#reshape 1D data to 2D
g=ax.plot_surface(lat.reshape(10, 10), lon.reshape(10, 10), depth.reshape(10, 10), cmap='hot',rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=fcolors, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False)
cbar=fig.colorbar(g,aspect=50)
cbar.set_label('slip', rotation=270, fontsize=14)
title("Published finite fault in 3-D")
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude [degrees]")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude [degrees]")
ax.set_zlabel("Depth [km]")
ax.invert_zaxis()
plt.show()
```